# How to pass ASP.NET Repeater items to JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps

On my, aspx page I have a repeater control that displays the lat long of the locations in the database.i want to pass the values returned from repeater into java script that display locations markers on google maps from sql server database.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var markers = [
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
                 {
                "title": '<%# Eval("City") %>',
                 "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
                 "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>',

             }
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        ,
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    ];
    </script>
   </form>
```

and this my code behind ,

```
 void GetData(string strRsult)
{
    XmlDataDocument xmlDataDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
    xmlDataDoc.LoadXml(strRsult);
    foreach (XmlNode n in xmlDataDoc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("Property"))
    {
        if (n.HasChildNodes)
        {
          List<Markers> markers = new List<Markers>();
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in n)
            {
                if (childNode.Name=="GEOData")
                {
                    markers.Add(new Markers
                    {
                        City = childNode.Attributes["City"].Value,
                        Longitude = childNode.Attributes["Longitude"].Value,
                        Latitude = childNode.Attributes["Latitude"].Value
                    });
                }

            }
            rptMarkers.DataSource = markers;
            rptMarkers.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

Comment: No need to read from the repeater, just create a json object from the repeaters datasource and pass it to `markers`

Comment: @DGibbs how can i create a json object

Comment: Something like this: `var jsonString = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dataSource);`.

Comment: i am update my code i want to look on it please.

Answer (score 0):

Code Behind

```
//Retrieves markers from somewhere and converts them to a JSON string
public string GetMarkersJson()
{
    List<Marker> markers = GetData("string");
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(markers); //using JSON.NET for serialization
}

//Parses an XML string and retrieves a list of Marker objects. Should probably go in a utility class somewhere, not in code behind
List<Marker> GetData(string strRsult)
{
    List<Marker> markers = new List<Marker>();
    XmlDataDocument xmlDataDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
    xmlDataDoc.LoadXml(strRsult);
    foreach (XmlNode n in xmlDataDoc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("Property"))
    {
        if (n.HasChildNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in n)
                {
                    if (childNode.Name=="GEOData")
                    {
                        markers.Add(new Marker
                        {
                            City = childNode.Attributes["City"].Value,
                            Longitude = childNode.Attributes["Longitude"].Value,
                            Latitude = childNode.Attributes["Latitude"].Value
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
    return markers;
}
```

Model

```
//Represents the data needed for each marker, with JSON.NET attributes to account for different property names we want to use in the JSON
public class Marker
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    public string City {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lat")]
    public string Latitude {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lng")]
    public string Longitude {get; set;}
}
```

Page

```
//Embed the JSON into the page and have JavaScript parse it
var markers = JSON.parse('<%= GetMarkersJson() %>');
```

Comment: @ahmeaad I see your update. You can change `GetData` to return a list of marker objects (instead of binding to the repeater) and use it in place of `Database.GetMarkers();` in my example. By the way, you should rename your class from `Markers` to `Marker` since an instance of the class should only represent one marker. The list would make it plural.

Comment: how i define json property it gives me syntax error.

Comment: @ahmeaad When you get an error, tell us exactly what it is so we don't have to guess. I'm assuming you got an error saying the type JsonProperty couldn't be found, which would mean you're missing a `using` statement. A simple problem, you can VS fix it for you by right clicking on the error and going to Resolve, depending on what version of VS you're using.

Comment: sorry ,yes exactly the error JsonProperty couldn't be found   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")] this one and others properties

Comment: @ahmeaad And did you try the right click and Resolve function that would automatically add the necessary `using` statements? Is Json.NET properly referenced in your project?

Answer (score -1):

your aspx code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<asp:literal runat="server" id="Literal1"></asp:literal>
</form>
```

your aspx.cs code

```
    //Parses an XML string and retrieves a list of Marker objects. Should probably go in a utility class somewhere, not in code behind
    protected void GetData(string strRsult)
    {
        List<Marker> markers = new List<Marker>();
        XmlDataDocument xmlDataDoc = new XmlDataDocument();
        xmlDataDoc.LoadXml(strRsult);
        //This line write script init in your html page
        Literal1.text = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var markers = [";

        foreach (XmlNode n in xmlDataDoc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("Property"))
        {
            if (n.HasChildNodes)
            {
//for any item you write directly the element{ tile:'yourTile', lat:'yourLat', lng:'yourLng' }
                foreach (XmlNode childNode in n)
                    {
                        if (childNode.Name=="GEOData")
                        {
                            literal1.text += "{title: '"+childNode.Attributes["City"].Value+"', lat: '"+childNode.Attributes["Longitude"].Value+"', lng: '"+childNode.Attributes["Latitude"].Valu+"'}";                        
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        //Write the scripts end
        Literal1.text += "];</script>";
    }
```

Comment: and how i'll pass value to repeater from code behind

Comment: i can not understand your example well.

Comment: in my example instead of using a repeater I use a literal, write javascript code directly in html page

no need to have a repeater

Comment: what the java script code i will write it if you know it you can mention it to me

Comment: i edited now with comments. if you not understand send me a mail with your code